# Error in query (1066): Not unique table/alias - how to fix the query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following mysql query, but i get the error Error in query (1066): Not unique table/alias: 'field_data_field_title'

I am also afraid that this error will occur in other tables once the above is fixed.
The syntax must be changed, since for instance there is this table, field_data_field_teuxos_tomos and in the query we have field_data_field_teuxos_tomos_node_entity_type (this is how drupal says handles inside the query...)
Also, there is not a table named og_membership_node but og_membership. Please see below its show create info.
The query shown needs a change from this strange drupal inner query to a normal mysql one, it needs a rephrasing, which i cannot figure out.

How should the below query be done in order not get errors?

```
            SELECT field_data_field_title.title AS field_data_field_title_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, field_data_field_title.nid AS field_data_field_title_nid, field_data_field_it_accession_nr.field_it_accession_nr_value AS field_data_field_it_accession_nr_field_it_accession_nr_value, field_data_field_collection.field_collection_nid AS field_data_field_collection_field_collection_nid, field_data_field_teuxos_year.field_teuxos_year_value AS field_data_field_teuxos_year_field_teuxos_year_value, field_data_field_it_volume.field_it_volume_value AS field_data_field_it_volume_field_it_volume_value, field_data_field_it_callnumber.field_it_callnumber_value AS field_data_field_it_callnumber_field_it_callnumber_value, 'node' AS field_data_field_item_type_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_accession_nr_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_collection_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_taksithetiko_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_avail_status_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_location_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_volume_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_volume_title_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_volume_year_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_pt_leg_created_date_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_condition_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_condition_other_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_charge_days_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_item_files_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_item_rights_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_files_channel_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_item_private_notes_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_item_bibliodesia_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_item_prosktisi_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_item_supplier_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_leg_price_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_invoice_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_invoice_date_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_xronologia_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_tomos_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_teuxos_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_pollaplotita_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_ektakto_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_item_link_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_antityponame_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_year_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_day_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_month_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_hidden_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_demeno_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_barcode_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_files_hidden_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_default_title_file_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_reader_dig_file_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_image_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_dewey_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_tl_uuid_node_entity_type
            FROM 
            node
            LEFT JOIN field_data_field_title ON node.nid = field_data_field_title.entity_id AND field_data_field_title.entity_type = 'node'
            LEFT JOIN field_data_field_title ON field_data_field_title.field_title_nid = field_data_field_title.nid
            LEFT JOIN og_membership_node ON node.nid = og_membership_node.etid AND og_membership_node.entity_type = 'node'
            LEFT JOIN field_data_field_deleted ON node.nid = field_data_field_deleted.entity_id AND field_data_field_deleted.field_deleted_value = '1'
            LEFT JOIN field_data_field_it_accession_nr ON node.nid = field_data_field_it_accession_nr.entity_id AND field_data_field_it_accession_nr.entity_type = 'node'
            LEFT JOIN field_data_field_collection ON node.nid = field_data_field_collection.entity_id AND field_data_field_collection.entity_type = 'node'
            LEFT JOIN field_data_field_teuxos_year ON node.nid = field_data_field_teuxos_year.entity_id AND field_data_field_teuxos_year.entity_type = 'node'
            LEFT JOIN field_data_field_it_volume ON node.nid = field_data_field_it_volume.entity_id AND field_data_field_it_volume.entity_type = 'node'
            LEFT JOIN field_data_field_it_callnumber ON node.nid = field_data_field_it_callnumber.entity_id AND field_data_field_it_callnumber.entity_type = 'node'
            WHERE (( (og_membership_node.gid = '672621' ) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('item')) AND (field_data_field_deleted.field_deleted_value IS NULL ) )))
            ORDER BY field_data_field_it_accession_nr_field_it_accession_nr_value ASC, field_data_field_collection_field_collection_nid ASC, field_data_field_teuxos_year_field_teuxos_year_value ASC, field_data_field_it_volume_field_it_volume_value ASC, field_data_field_it_callnumber_field_it_callnumber_value ASC
            LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
        
          
        
              CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_title` (
                  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
                  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
                  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
                  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
                  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
                  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
                  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
                  `field_title_nid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
                  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
                  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
                  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
                  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
                  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
                  KEY `language` (`language`),
                  KEY `field_title_nid` (`field_title_nid`)
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 42 (field_title)'
            
                CREATE TABLE `node` (
                  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'The primary identifier for a node.',
                  `vid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The current node_revision.vid version identifier.',
                  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The node_type.type of this node.',
                  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The languages.language of this node.',
                  `title` varchar(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The users.uid that owns this node; initially, this is the user that created it.',
                  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Boolean indicating whether the node is published (visible to non-administrators).',
                  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The Unix timestamp when the node was created.',
                  `changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The Unix timestamp when the node was most recently saved.',
                  `comment` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Whether comments are allowed on this node: 0 = no, 1 = closed (read only), 2 = open (read/write).',
                  `promote` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Boolean indicating whether the node should be displayed on the front page.',
                  `sticky` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Boolean indicating whether the node should be displayed at the top of lists in which it appears.',
                  `tnid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The translation set id for this node, which equals the node id of the source post in each set.',
                  `translate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this translation page needs to be updated.',
                  PRIMARY KEY (`nid`),
                  UNIQUE KEY `vid` (`vid`),
                  KEY `node_changed` (`changed`),
                  KEY `node_created` (`created`),
                  KEY `node_frontpage` (`promote`,`status`,`sticky`,`created`),
                  KEY `node_status_type` (`status`,`type`,`nid`),
                  KEY `node_type` (`type`(4)),
                  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
                  KEY `tnid` (`tnid`),
                  KEY `translate` (`translate`),
                  KEY `language` (`language`),
                  KEY `node_title_type` (`title`(250),`type`(4))
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14255011 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='The base table for nodes.'
            
            CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_it_accession_nr` (
              `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
              `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
              `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
              `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
              `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
              `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
              `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
              `field_it_accession_nr_value` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
              `field_it_accession_nr_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
              KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
              KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
              KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
              KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
              KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
              KEY `language` (`language`),
              KEY `field_it_accession_nr_format` (`field_it_accession_nr_format`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 56 (field_it_accession_nr)'
        
        CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_collection` (
          `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
          `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
          `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
          `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
          `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
          `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
          `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
          `field_collection_nid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
          KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
          KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
          KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
          KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
          KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
          KEY `language` (`language`),
          KEY `field_collection_nid` (`field_collection_nid`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 11 (field_collection)'
        
        
            CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_teuxos_pollaplotita` (
              `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
              `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
              `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
              `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
              `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
              `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
              `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
              `field_teuxos_pollaplotita_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
              KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
              KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
              KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
              KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
              KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
              KEY `language` (`language`),
              KEY `field_teuxos_pollaplotita_value` (`field_teuxos_pollaplotita_value`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 137 (field_teuxos_pollaplotita)'
        
        
            CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_teuxos_tomos` (
              `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
              `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
              `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
              `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
              `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
              `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
              `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
              `field_teuxos_tomos_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
              `field_teuxos_tomos_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
              KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
              KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
              KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
              KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
              KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
              KEY `language` (`language`),
              KEY `field_teuxos_tomos_format` (`field_teuxos_tomos_format`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 134 (field_teuxos_tomos)'
    
    CREATE TABLE `og_membership` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'The group membership’s unique ID.',
      `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Reference to a group membership type.',
      `etid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The entity ID.',
      `entity_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type (e.g. node, comment, etc’).',
      `gid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The group’s unique ID.',
      `group_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The group’s entity type (e.g. node, comment, etc’).',
      `state` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The state of the group content.',
      `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The Unix timestamp when the group content was created.',
      `field_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The name of the field holding the group ID, the OG memebership is associated with.',
      `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The languages.language of this membership.',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `entity` (`etid`,`entity_type`),
      KEY `group` (`gid`,`group_type`),
      KEY `group_type` (`group_type`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14456018 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='The group membership table.'

CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_it_volume` (
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_it_volume_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_it_volume_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  KEY `field_it_volume_format` (`field_it_volume_format`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 17 (field_it_volume)'

CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_it_callnumber` (
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_it_callnumber_value` varchar(511) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_it_callnumber_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  KEY `field_it_callnumber_format` (`field_it_callnumber_format`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 15 (field_it_callnumber)'

CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_it_accession_nr` (
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_it_accession_nr_value` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_it_accession_nr_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  KEY `field_it_accession_nr_format` (`field_it_accession_nr_format`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 56 (field_it_accession_nr)'
```

Comment: Can you add the description of the tables involved in this query?

Comment: which command would you like me to run so as to provide best info? thank you for your reply

Comment: You could run pg_dump for each of the tables, as in "pg_dump -U your_user your_database -t your_table --schema-only" and copy the create table and paste it unto your question.

Comment: i am afraid the question will be  unreadable if i put here all tables

Comment: It wouldn't, but if you would add node, og_membership_node, and a couple of the "field_data_field_*" tables, it would be enough.  I'll be AFK for an hour or so.

Comment: query needs rewriting, to a normal mysql query.  og_membership_node does not exist, the table is og_membership. I have updated the description of my problem, it seems i need to rephrase the query into normal mysql.

Comment: Couldn't u use Drupal's database api (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/group/database/8.2.x) in stead of writing your own queries?

Comment: If a colleague had come to me for support with a query like this one, he, if it was a "he", would have been happy we were working on the first floor only.

Comment: What is the use of this query?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Drupal, Wordpress and other CMSs have similar EAV-like structured tables to allow for extensible structures. This leads to queries like this one. The naming, yeah, ..., it's horrendous.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ,  shouldn't the developer use the APIs so  that he doesn't need to bother with those monstruosities?  Just looking for Drupal's database structure, I came across that advice.  Having dealt with Fatwire (now Oracle) for ten years, I've had my share of mad queries.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yeah, they should of course. Unless they know what they are doing (which doesn't look the case here for whoever wrote this one)

Comment: the use of this query is to get a view out of drupal. I am not familiar with the drupal api, i am trying to get all data out in order to migrate. Due to many nodes, modules that allow for exporting of data cause timeouts

Comment: A web interface is not designed for batch jobs.  But it should be possible to increase the timeout for specific requests, even letting the webserver wait indefinitely, until the request succeeds.  What is your webserver and your OS?  Are you aware of https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export ?

Comment: There is the memory limit also which causes me the problem. yes, this module claims it is running the query i have in my question. Below link shows how one can see what it is running, but i am now trying to alter the query, since it is not working directly in mysql. https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal/display-view-sql-query/

Comment: I've got little experience with MySQL, but couldn't you find the exact queries using the "slow query" log?

Comment: i will look at this. i have searched in the slow query, but it has many other queries, so i was lost. i am trying to get results from the above query. One issue i have is how to get from field_data_field_title, which has a column title_nodeid, with a number, which if searched in the node table, has as its value the real title with words. How this select should be? Your experience is much more than mine, and your kindness and patience is appreciated

Comment: i am executing the query i have made, and i get Error in query (1114): The table '/tmp/#sql_49f_0' is full. Perhaps if i use a client a desktop client like Heidisql i will be more lucky?

Answer (score 2):

You're joining twice with field_data_field_title:

```
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_title
  ON  node.nid = field_data_field_title.entity_id
  AND field_data_field_title.entity_type = 'node'
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_title
  ON field_data_field_title.field_title_nid = field_data_field_title.nid
```

It doesn't make sense to me, but if you need field_data_field_title twice, you need to use aliases, as in:

```
SELECT
  fdf_title1.title AS field_data_field_title_title,
  node.nid AS nid,
  node.created AS node_created,
  field_data_field_title.nid
    AS field_data_field_title_nid,
  field_data_field_it_accession_nr.field_it_accession_nr_value
    AS field_data_field_it_accession_nr_field_it_accession_nr_value,
  field_data_field_collection.field_collection_nid
    AS field_data_field_collection_field_collection_nid,
  field_data_field_teuxos_year.field_teuxos_year_value
    AS field_data_field_teuxos_year_field_teuxos_year_value,
  field_data_field_it_volume.field_it_volume_value
    AS field_data_field_it_volume_field_it_volume_value,
  field_data_field_it_callnumber.field_it_callnumber_value
    AS field_data_field_it_callnumber_field_it_callnumber_value,
  'node' AS field_data_field_item_type_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_accession_nr_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_collection_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_taksithetiko_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_avail_status_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_location_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_volume_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_volume_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_volume_title_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_volume_year_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_pt_leg_created_date_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_condition_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_condition_other_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_charge_days_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_item_files_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_item_rights_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_files_channel_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_item_private_notes_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_item_bibliodesia_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_item_prosktisi_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_item_supplier_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_leg_price_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_invoice_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_it_invoice_date_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_xronologia_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_tomos_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_teuxos_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_pollaplotita_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_ektakto_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_item_link_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_antityponame_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_year_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_day_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_teuxos_month_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_hidden_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_demeno_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_barcode_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_files_hidden_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_default_title_file_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_reader_dig_file_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_image_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_dewey_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_field_tl_uuid_node_entity_type
  FROM node
  LEFT JOIN field_data_field_title fdf_title1
    ON node.nid = fdf_title1.entity_id
    AND fdf_title1.entity_type = 'node'
  LEFT JOIN field_data_field_title
    ON field_data_field_title.field_title_nid = field_data_field_title.nid
  LEFT JOIN og_membership_node
    ON node.nid = og_membership_node.etid
    AND og_membership_node.entity_type = 'node'
  LEFT JOIN field_data_field_deleted
    ON node.nid = field_data_field_deleted.entity_id
    AND field_data_field_deleted.field_deleted_value = '1'
  LEFT JOIN field_data_field_it_accession_nr
    ON node.nid = field_data_field_it_accession_nr.entity_id
    AND field_data_field_it_accession_nr.entity_type = 'node'
  LEFT JOIN field_data_field_collection
    ON node.nid = field_data_field_collection.entity_id
    AND field_data_field_collection.entity_type = 'node'
  LEFT JOIN field_data_field_teuxos_year
    ON node.nid = field_data_field_teuxos_year.entity_id
    AND field_data_field_teuxos_year.entity_type = 'node'
  LEFT JOIN field_data_field_it_volume
    ON node.nid = field_data_field_it_volume.entity_id
    AND field_data_field_it_volume.entity_type = 'node'
  LEFT JOIN field_data_field_it_callnumber
    ON node.nid = field_data_field_it_callnumber.entity_id
    AND field_data_field_it_callnumber.entity_type = 'node'
  WHERE og_membership_node.gid = '672621'
    AND node.status = '1'
    AND node.type IN  ('item')
    AND field_data_field_deleted.field_deleted_value IS NULL
  ORDER BY
    field_data_field_it_accession_nr_field_it_accession_nr_value ASC,
    field_data_field_collection_field_collection_nid ASC,
    field_data_field_teuxos_year_field_teuxos_year_value ASC,
    field_data_field_it_volume_field_it_volume_value ASC,
    field_data_field_it_callnumber_field_it_callnumber_value ASC
  LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

(look for alias fdf_title1).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.blah, b1.junk, b2.name, ...
    FROM tableA AS a
    JOIN tableB AS b1 ON b1.this = a.something
    JOIN tableB AS b2 ON b2.that = a.else
    WHERE a.x = 5
      AND b1.y = 8
    ORDER BY b2.date;
```

Give each table a unique alias, even if the table is not unique.  Then qualify each column with the table it comes from.

Comment: i am executing the query i have made, and i get Error in query (1114): The table '/tmp/#sql_49f_0' is full. Perhaps if i use a client a desktop client like Heidisql i will be more lucky? i have a really huge db, and i cannot get a result from the query at all

Comment: @xamefa - That says that a temp table is being built, but it is so big that it exceeded available disk space, at least in `/tmp`.  Check the disk layout.  Check that you have `ON` clauses between tables.